# Twilio Incoming SMS Webhook for Admin Access URL

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have configured and have the code written out in my Django app to integrate Twilio SMS sending and receiving. It is successfully sending messages.

However, the problem I'm coming across is that the public facing URL I have to communicate with the webhook and TwiML is only accessible for the admin so you have to have a certain authentication to access the messaging dashboard (where the messages are coming in). I'm not sure how to configure this in Twilio

I was wondering how I can configure this webhook in Twilio to ensure a user can respond via SMS from their phone and the message will display in the messaging dashboard within the app.

I'm not super familiar with Twilio or this situation so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio's serverless offering, [Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets), could help you out here. It's not available in Python but uses Node.js instead. However, it's pretty straightforward, allows you to call your own URLs with any authentication mechanisms, and helps you store secrets securely.

Here's a small sample snippet from the docs:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  const response = await axios
    .get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');

  twiml
    .message(`Hello, ${event.From}! Enjoy this doge!`)
    .media(response.data.message);

  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```